# How Can I Pass a VBA Class Variable to a Module Function ByRef?

Tags: excel, vba, class, variables, pass-by-reference

A VBA Class Object can be Passed to a Module Function, and the Function can then Modify the Class Object's Variables.

However, I can't find a way to Pass an Individual Class Variable to do the same ie Modify the Individual Class Variable

To illustrate in Excel;

```
'Create a Class Module (named Class1) with One Variable;

 Public c1Long As Long

'Copy the following into a Code Module;

Public Cls1 As Class1

Function SetCls1LongTo2(ioCls1 As Class1)
    ioCls1.c1Long = 2
End Function

Function SetCls1LongTo3(ByRef ioLong As Long)
    Debug.Print "iPar=" & ioLong
    ioLong = 3
    Debug.Print "oPar=" & ioLong
End Function
```

Now run the following commands from the Immediate Window;

```
Set Cls1=New Class1
Call SetCls1LongTo2(Cls1)
? Cls1.c1Long                       '2 as expected
Call SetCls1LongTo3(Cls1.c1Long)    'the Debug.Prints are "iPar=2" and "oPar=3" as expected
? Cls1.c1Long                       'still 2?
```

The "ByRef" in SetCls1LongTo3() should be redundant, and I've tried it without;
I've also tried declaring Let and Get Properties for c1Long in Cls1, all with the same result

It's as if an Entire Class Object can be Passed By Reference, but an Individual Class Variable can only be Passed By Value?

Can anyone please explain this behaviour, and hopefully also provide a solution ?

Comment: in most programming languages there isn't even an option to pass "primitive" / "value" types by reference. There are workarounds like putting them into an array of length 1 (but those are usually discouraged). Passing those types byRef (and changing them) makes your functions impure, reducing readability and the ability to unit-test. - So my question basically is: Why do you need an object property to be passed ByRef. What requires this (and can't be solved in another way - like just passing the object)

Comment: At first, I thought it had to do with the Immediate Window (IW), but this also occurs if you put the code you suggested for the IW inside of a module. It seems like `Member variables` aren't accessed the same way the usual global or module-level variables are: the internal VBA pipeline responsible with retrieving a `value type` inside a class/object passes it as `ByVal` no matter how it is requested by the sub/function.

Comment: Yes L-J, per my post passing the Entire Class Object works, but seems a hugely inefficient if all I want to do is change one of it's Variables

Comment: You're not passing the whole object, just a pointer to it.

Comment: Thanks Tim, maybe so, but passing the Entire Object then makes the function specific to that Class (eg Class1 in SetCls1LongTo2), whereas SetCls1LongTo3 acts on Any Long Variable - except when it is a Class Variable